# Failed xml validation "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a:.."

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have this xml (right below): the tag `<property>` may contain any number of `<action>`, `<validation>`,`<lov>` elements in ANY ORDER and MIXED UP

```
<!-- ... -->
<property>
    <action>foo</action>
    <validation>bar</validation>
    <lov>baz</lov>
</property>

<property>
    <action>foo1</action>
    <validation>bar</validation>
    <action>foo2</action> 
</property>

<property>
    <action>foo1</action>
    <action>foo2</action> 
    <action>foo3</action>     
</property>
```

now I'm building an xsd (in Eclipse) to have this xml validated and I came up with this (using `<xsd:all>`):

```
<!-- ... -->
<complexType name="propertyType">
    <all minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <element name="validation" type="tns:validationType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        <element name="lov" type="tns:lovType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></element>
        <element name="action" type="tns:actionType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></element>

    </all>
</complexType>
```

BUT validation fails

```
<!-- ... -->
<property>
    <action>foo</action>
    <validation>bar</validation>
    <lov>baz</lov>
</property>

<property>
    <action>foo1</action>
    <validation>bar</validation>
    <action>foo2</action>         <!-- ERROR !? -->
</property>

<property>
    <action>foo1</action>
    <action>foo2</action>        <!-- ERROR !? -->
    <action>foo3</action>     
</property>
```

with this error

cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'action'. One of 
 '{"http://www.example.org/dm":validation, "http://www.example.org/dm":lov}' is expected.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: If you're using an XSD 1.1 processor I would expect validation to succeed, if you're using an XSD 1.0 processor I would expect the schema to be rejected (`maxOccurs` in `xs:all` is restricted to 1).

Comment: thanks @MichaelKay. I didn't notice at first but Eclipse (4.5.2) is complaining about my xsd with `error cos-all-limited.2: The {max occurs} of an element in an 'all' model group must be 0 or 1. The value '-1' for element 'validation' is invalid.` So I think my question should be reworded as: "How to configure Eclipse in order to use an XSD 1.1 processor for XML modeling?"

Comment: Not being an Eclipse user, I'm afraid I can't help you with that one.